# VScode asking to run python code with code-runner or terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I've always used the code runner extension and never had any problem.
But for some unknown reason, vscode is now asking me this:
[options to run code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q4is.png)

It's very strange because the code runner setting to run in terminal is already set to false, like:

- "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,

I don't know how to fix this and it's really annoying have to select the run option everytime.

Comment: Hello try changing the value to `true` and restart vscode.

Comment: Yes, no results. The code runner run short cut (ctrl+alt+n) is working fine, that's very odd. Does it have something to do with the venv settings?

Comment: In the bottom left corner of the main window what is the python version that VScode uses?

Comment: @João Artur -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Comment: Sorry, been a little bit busy. So, the version is python 3.9.2 (i think). I don't know if it has something to do when the file was created, because new .py files don't seems to have this issue. Anyways, I'm setting myself to use as many shortcuts as I can to speed things up and become more efficient. I appreciate all the help =)

Comment: I found that it started happening after updating python extension to version 2021.3.x . You can stick to the latest 2021.2.x version until it's fixed by python or code runner.
Here you may find some more details
https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/752

Answer (score 0):

This display is normal. Previously, when we used the "Code Runner" extension, the run button "`Run Code`" provided by it would overwrite the "`Run Python File in Terminal`" button provided by the "Python" extension. But now, these two buttons are integrated, which allows us to choose two different ways of performing the display: in "`OUTPUT`" or "`Terminal`".

For setting `"code-runner.runInTerminal": false,` it determines whether the "code runner" runs in the "Terminal", ("Run Code" is output in "OUTPUT" by default, which does not support user input but displays more clearly, while "Run Python File in Terminal" executes code in "Terminal", which supports user interaction. They are different in the way the command is executed.)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. But I got a weird solution:

1. For coding in python you just need to uncheck the " Code-runner:
   Show-Run Icon In Editor Title Menu "
2. For coding in c/cpp you need to check that box

Comment: wow, that actually did work. However, the output is been shown on the python terminal, not on code-runner, even with "code-runner.runInTerminal": false setting.